# Is this a run-on sentence, if so, why?

Tags: grammar, run-on-sentence

If this is a run on sentence, can I separate it properly? I would like to still maintain the ideas close correlation with each other.

- In this, Hesse tells the reader that we cannot equate the concepts of teaching and experiencing, for to truly understand something we must experience it, which may not be a clear cut path.

Comment: I agree the sentence is not a run-on example, however I would normally use a hyphen in both "run-on" and "clear-cut", since they are compound adjectives and they usually require one (but not after "ly" adverbs, such as "highly placed source".

Comment: Added to correct - a hyphen is used between an adverb and a past participle (highly-placed) operating as a compound, but not between an adverb and an adjective (a highly intelligent woman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No is the short answer.

[In this], **Hesse tells the reader that we cannot equate the concepts of teaching and experiencing**, [for to truly understand something we must experience it, [which may not be a clear cut path]].

There is only one main clause (in bold); the other elements (bracketed) are a preposition phrase, *in this*, and two subordinate clauses, the ones beginning with *for* and *which*.

So, no run-on here.

Answer (score 3):

A run-on sentence is not a sentence that has two many clauses or that otherwise goes on too long. It is a sentence that contains two or more clauses that are not connected by a proper conjunction or punctuation. *I went home, then I had dinner* is a run-on sentence (also called a comma splice) because *then* is an adverb, not a conjunction (it can be fixed by adding *and* or changing the comma to a semi-colon). In the sentence you provide, the second and third clauses both begin with subordinate conjunctions, *for* and *which*. Yours is not a run-on sentence, and is perfectly grammatical as is.